# Solving ERROR_CAPTCHA_UNSOLVABLE while using 2captcha API with Selenium for a Google reCAPTCHA: What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, recaptcha, 2captcha

I am getting the error `ERROR_CAPTCHA_UNSOLVABLE` while using the `2captcha API` service to solve a google recaptcha.
When I manually solve this captcha I have to click the check box and then select the images and then click on verify button. Here is how I am trying to solve this captcha and I am using selenium to get elements.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,23).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,'//div[@class="g-recaptcha"]')))
google_recaptcha = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//div[@class="g-recaptcha"]').get_attribute('data-sitekey')
print("SOLVING CAPTCHA")
print(google_recaptcha)
result = solve(google_recaptcha,url)
result = result['code']
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.ID,'g-recaptcha-response')))
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-response').innerHTML = "+"'"+result+"'")
```

and here is my `solve` function

```
def solve(siteKey,url):
    sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))))

    api_key = os.getenv('APIKEY_2CAPTCHA', 'adsasd')
    solver = TwoCaptcha(api_key)

    try:
        result = solver.recaptcha(
            sitekey=siteKey,
            url='https://2captcha.com/demo/recaptcha-v2')

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    else:
        return result
```

I am passing the current tab URL and the site key. but whenever I try this I get the exception ERROR_CAPTCHA_UNSOLVABLE. Is there any other way to solve this or I am in the wrong direction? Please guide me I am very new to this.

Answer (score 1):

First of All, Check that are you getting the site key of the captcha?
The Method you are using `google_recaptcha = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//div[@class="g-recaptcha"]').get_attribute('data-sitekey')` most of the time it doesn't work to get the sitekey.

use this method to get the sitekey:

```
`try:
        recaptchaContainer = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME  , "class or Id of the Captcha container ")
        if recaptchaContainer:
            print('founded recaptcha container')
            try:
          
                iframe_element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'iframe[title="reCAPTCHA"]')
                iframe_src = iframe_element.get_attribute("src")
                print(iframe_src)
                params= iframe_src.split('&')
                sitekey = None
                for param in params:
                    if param.startswith("k="):
                        sitekey = param.split('=')[1]
                        break
                        
                # Print the siteke
                print("The sitekey in Iframe is:", sitekey)
            except Exception as e:
                print(f'Error Getting the Sitekey{e}')
                
            captcha_code = solve_captcha(current_url,sitekey)
        else:
            print('Logged in without Recaptcha')
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Error Occured in this Block of Code:  {e}')
```

Once You Got the site Key this will be easy for you to solve the captcha

Further More You'll get Help from this gist https://gist.github.com/2captcha/2ee70fa1130e756e1693a5d4be4d8c70

Comment: Or instead of getting site key from iframe src you can get the page source and save it in html file then with the help of bs4 read the html file and then using 'g-recaptcha' this class to get its attribute